# Get key of dictionary on JSON parse with SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I want to get "key of dictionary" (that's what I called, not sure if it is right name) on this JSON

```
{
  "People": {
    "People with nice hair": {
      "name": "Peter John",
      "age": 12,
      "books": [
        {
          "title": "Breaking Bad",
          "release": "2011"
        },
        {
          "title": "Twilight",
          "release": "2012"
        },
        {
          "title": "Gone Wild",
          "release": "2013"
        }
      ]
    },
    "People with jacket": {
      "name": "Jason Bourne",
      "age": 15,
      "books": [
        {
          "title": "Breaking Bad",
          "release": "2011"
        },
        {
          "title": "Twilight",
          "release": "2012"
        },
        {
          "title": "Gone Wild",
          "release": "2013"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

First of all, I already created my People struct that will be used to map from those JSON. 
Here is my people struct

```
struct People {
    var peopleLooks:String?
    var name:String?
    var books = [Book]()
}
```

And here is my Book struct

```
struct Book {
    var title:String?
    var release:String?
}
```

From that JSON, I created engine with Alamofire and SwiftyJSON that will be called in my controller via completion handler

```
Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { response in
   if response.result.error == nil {
      let json = JSON(response.result.value!)
      success(json)
   }
}
```

And here is what I do in my controller

```
Engine.instance.getPeople(request, success:(JSON?)->void),
   success:{ (json) in

   // getting all the json object
   let jsonRecieve = JSON((json?.dictionaryObject)!)

   // get list of people
   let peoples = jsonRecieve["People"]

   // from here, we try to map people into our struct that I don't know how.
}
```

My question is, how to map my `peoples` from `jsonRecieve["People"]` into my struct? 
I want `"People with nice hair"` as a value of `peopleLooks` on my `People` struct. I thought `"People with nice hair"` is kind of key of dictionary or something, but I don't know how to get that.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you iterate through dictionaries, for instance

```
for peeps in peoples
```

You can access key with

```
peeps.0
```

and value with

```
peeps.1
```

Comment: Yeaaaahh, you saved my day! Thank you soooo much, @NickCatib! Will approve this answer in few minutes.

Comment: Very helpful :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use key, value loop.

```
for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in json["People"] {
   // you can use key and subJson here.
}
```